# Error in XML parsing in the dtd file "Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type... "

Tags: xml, sax, saxparseexception

My address.dtd file is as follows. When I tried to parse my address.xml file using SAXParserFactory, the exception come as,

"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/samitha/svnrepo/XML/XMLParserTest/src/address.dtd; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 22; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "province"."

```
<!-- address.dtd -->
<!ELEMENT address (name,house-id?,village,city,postal-code,country) >
<!ELEMENT name (personal:title*,(first-name|first-init),last-name+)>
<!ELEMENT house-id (houses:title,NAME)>
<!ELEMENT personal:name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT village (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST city district CDATA #REQUIRED 
               province CDATA (Southern|Western|Nothern|Eastern) "One Sri 
Lanka"> 
<!ELEMENT postal-code (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT personal:title (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT first-name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT first-init (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT last-name (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT houses:title (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA) >
```

address.xml file looks as follows.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE address SYSTEM "address.dtd">


<!-- Some namespaces are declared in this-->
<address 
    xmlns:personal="Personal things"
    xmlns:houses="Regarding to houses"

>
    <name  xml:space='preserve'>  
        <personal:title>Mr.     </personal:title>
        <first-name>Samitha       </first-name>
        <last-name>Chathuranga</last-name>
    </name>
    <house-id>
        <houses:title>107 B</houses:title>
        <NAME>Sam&apos;s Home</NAME>
        <!--  An intnal entity is used for the single quote in House Name here-->
    </house-id>
    <village>Poramba</village>
    <city district="Galle" province="Southern">AG</city>
    <postal-code>80300</postal-code>
    <country>Sri Lanka</country>
</address>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute's datatype can be an enumeration or CDATA, but it can't be both. You should remove the `CDATA`:

```
<!ATTLIST city 
      district CDATA #REQUIRED 
      province (Southern|Western|Nothern|Eastern) "One Sri Lanka">
```

Source:
http://www.xmlfiles.com/dtd/dtd_attributes.asp

However there's still a problem here. The value "One Sri Lanka" does not match any of the four values you have listed there. What is your thinking behind that?

Comment: "One Sri Lanka" is the default value.

Comment: Ah.. kk.. I have done that mistake too.. Default value should be one of the Given values. So giving "One Sri Lanka" is wrong. It can be "Southern" or "Western" or etc... Thanks a lot.